# prevent downloading photos in photobox

Tags: javascript, photo, photo-gallery

How to prevent apparent downloading photos when displaying them with **photobox**?
I've disabled right-click on thumbnails shown on website but when I start slideshow with **photobox** I still can do it.
Here's the part where I display photos on website:

```html
<div class="gallery">
   <a href="<?=$path1; ?>">
   <img src="<?= $path1; ?>">
   </a>
   <div contentEditable="true"><?=pathinfo($path1, PATHINFO_FILENAME)?></div>
</div>
```

Here photobox displaying

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.gallery').photobox('a',{ time:0 });
    });
    </script>
```

And here right-click preventing

```js
<script>
$("a").mousedown(function(e) {
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I edited and hope everything is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this prevents right clicking on the elements:

```
<script>
    $("a").mousedown(function(e) {
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Because I've tested that and the context menu still appears.
Since you're also passing `e` to the function but not doing anything to it.
But this one does:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").mousedown(function(e) {
            document.addEventListener('contextmenu', e =>
                e.preventDefault()
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note the `ready()` event listener to wait until the DOM has loaded for it to affect all `"a"` elements.
Another thing about this is that such rules can be overriden right from the browser debugger tools so it's not effective to prevent right clicking on the elements.

Comment: thank you! yes you were right, I think I should have binded context menu first. anyway your answer was very helpful and now it finally works, thanks